# kafka rebalancing taking a long time for Deleting Obsolete state directory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Whenever i try to spawn up a consumer for my consumer group, Kafka takes a lot of time to rebalance and gets stuck on this log

```
Deleting obsolete state directory 0_45 for task 0_45 as 601021ms has elapsed (cleanup delay is 600000ms).
```

I have 8 streaming threads for the topic i want to subscribe to and that topic has 64 partitions.

Everything like `max.poll.records`, `session.timeout.ms` are all default values in kafka. I tried to find a resolution to this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can configure the delay to cleanup old task directories via `state.cleanup.delay.ms` (cf https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#optional-configuration-parameters). However, I am not sure how this would related to long rebalances. What version do you use? Do you do stateful processing?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yeah, it's stateful prcessing. I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Did you try to increase the config?